# Fluid inline element gap spacing

Tags: html, css

Is there a way for fluid inline elements in different containers to have the same gap spacing?

Simple example:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
  <li>
    <span>Row1Col1</span><span style="margin-left: 10px">Row1Col2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Row2Col1</span><span style="margin-left: 10px">Row2Col2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the above example, the columns are separated by a margin, however, this does not work when the columns become wider/smaller or are of different widths - see below:

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
  <li>
    <span>Row1Col1-abcd</span><span style="margin-left: 10px">Row1Col2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Row2Col1</span><span style="margin-left: 10px">Row2Col2-abcd</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/Falven/pen/QBwxLV

Answer (score 0):

You should use flexbox for this.

A really good way to learn flexbox is to play flexbox froggy:
https://flexboxfroggy.com/

```
.container {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: Can you expand on how you would use flex-box to solve the above issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can use flexbox to achieve this requirement.

There is also a good guide from css-tricks that you can read easily.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.list-unstyled li {
  flex: 1 100%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: space-evenly;
}

.list-unstyled li span {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <span>Col1</span><span>Col2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Col1</span><span>Col2</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <span>Above ASDFW</span><span>ABOVE</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>BELOW</span><span>BELOW @!#!@#</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. In your example Row1Col1 and Row1Col2 are on different rows (li's).

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Yes, they somehow lookalike, so I mistaken them as you expected. Sorry for that, I adjusted the code now. You can check again

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately, the rows do not line up...
https://imgur.com/a/jvM9N90